# Team Question ranking game problem

Tags: ranking

We have question game with Yes or No type of answers. There are multiple teams participating and every team have different number of players. Each player answers to questions. Players can join the game after few of questions has been ended. How to count fairly the all score for the team so we can rank a team?

Comment: Can members of a team communicate with each other, so do larger teams have an advantage?

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the number of correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: If you have more than one statistic, you have more than one metric. I see an almost infinite number of ranking possibilities. Here's the ones that jump out at me:

1. Use the average correct answer percentage for the players on the team.
2. If you have tournaments, have a ranking for tournament win percentage. (You could also use a chess-style ranking to determine the ranking of tournaments.)
3. Track how many people get a question right wrong. A player's score for getting a question right is `(1 - q)` where q is the % of people that got that question right. If you get it wrong, you also lose q points. This actually means as other people answer questions, your score may go up or down (which it should, since the purpose is to make it relative to the other players.)

i'll edit more in as I think of them (if I think of them). I really like option 3 though!